# Time Zone on User Reports

Tags: timezone

If I run a report on user login date/time, what time zone is that show in? My user account's time zone or the user's on the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce always display time in **user's timezone**, but it will save the time as **UTC time**  in the database.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should display the User's timezone.  (In fact, I think Salesforce always displays datetimes in the user's context).

The best way to figure this out is to dig right in and try it out!  (i.e. change your default Timezone on *your* User page, and see what happens.)

Comment: That was actually a great idea. Sure enough, changed my profile time zone and the report time changed as well. Great suggestion. Thanks.